# A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony and I get a circular error dependancy when i try to get data from Database.

This is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BeerRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BeerRepository::class)]
class Beer
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $description;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Saveurs::class, inversedBy: 'beers')]
    private $saveurs;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Origine::class, inversedBy: 'beers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $origine;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Style::class, inversedBy: 'beers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $style;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Couleur::class, inversedBy: 'beers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $couleur;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Container::class, inversedBy: 'beers')]
    private $container;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $eye_description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $mouth_description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $noise_description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $amertume;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $acidite;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $vivacite;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $puissance;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $rondeur;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $fruite;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->saveurs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->container = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Saveurs>
     */
    public function getSaveurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->saveurs;
    }

    public function addSaveur(Saveurs $saveur): self
    {
        if (!$this->saveurs->contains($saveur)) {
            $this->saveurs[] = $saveur;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSaveur(Saveurs $saveur): self
    {
        $this->saveurs->removeElement($saveur);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrigine(): ?Origine
    {
        return $this->origine;
    }

    public function setOrigine(?Origine $origine): self
    {
        $this->origine = $origine;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getStyle(): ?Style
    {
        return $this->style;
    }

    public function setStyle(?Style $style): self
    {
        $this->style = $style;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCouleur(): ?Couleur
    {
        return $this->couleur;
    }

    public function setCouleur(?Couleur $couleur): self
    {
        $this->couleur = $couleur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Container>
     */
    public function getContainer(): Collection
    {
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function addContainer(Container $container): self
    {
        if (!$this->container->contains($container)) {
            $this->container[] = $container;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeContainer(Container $container): self
    {
        $this->container->removeElement($container);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEyeDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->eye_description;
    }

    public function setEyeDescription(string $eye_description): self
    {
        $this->eye_description = $eye_description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMouthDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mouth_description;
    }

    public function setMouthDescription(string $mouth_description): self
    {
        $this->mouth_description = $mouth_description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNoiseDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->noise_description;
    }

    public function setNoiseDescription(string $noise_description): self
    {
        $this->noise_description = $noise_description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmertume(): ?int
    {
        return $this->amertume;
    }

    public function setAmertume(int $amertume): self
    {
        $this->amertume = $amertume;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAcidite(): ?int
    {
        return $this->acidite;
    }

    public function setAcidite(int $acidite): self
    {
        $this->acidite = $acidite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVivacite(): ?int
    {
        return $this->vivacite;
    }

    public function setVivacite(int $vivacite): self
    {
        $this->vivacite = $vivacite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPuissance(): ?int
    {
        return $this->puissance;
    }

    public function setPuissance(int $puissance): self
    {
        $this->puissance = $puissance;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRondeur(): ?int
    {
        return $this->rondeur;
    }

    public function setRondeur(int $rondeur): self
    {
        $this->rondeur = $rondeur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFruite(): ?int
    {
        return $this->fruite;
    }

    public function setFruite(int $fruite): self
    {
        $this->fruite = $fruite;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And this is my method to get data :

```
 #[Route('/beer/{id}', name: 'getBeer', methods: ["GET"])]
    public function getOneBeer($id): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $beer = $entityManager->getRepository(Beer::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

        if(!$beer) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Beer with id ' . $id . ' doesn\'t exist');
        }

        return $this->json($beer);
        
    }
```

I think that the problem come from "saveurs" but not sure...
I tried to serialize it with SerializerInterface but it doesn't work

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marleen I didn't understand how to use groups before, but your link helps me!